# Console HighCharts errors broke visualisation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Hi everyone!** I am working on a website (`Laravel 5.2`) which uses a total of 16 different `HighCharts` to visualise data. I have finished the visualisation about two weeks ago, and didn't pay much attention to it anymore because it was working. Yesterday, I noticed that only 4 of the 16 `HighCharts` are working. I have programmed a lot during since I had finished the visualisation, so I am uncertain why it stopped working all of a sudden. First off, I downloaded the packages which I use for HighCharts, because I thought it might be a update problem. This didn't have any effect.. I started debugging using the console of Google Chrome. This showed the following errors:

[image]

Which are all problems in the HighCharts JavaScript files I have downloaded. I am kinda lost here, and uncertain what broke half of my site. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens the second time `Highcharts` is loaded in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined.

You must do to contain one single script:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

OR

`Highcharts.Chart` constructor and all features of `Highcharts` are included in `Highstock`, so if you are running `Chart` and `StockChart` in combination..then you will receive error.

Comment: Hi! I only have this `<script type="text/javascript" src={{asset('/js/highcharts.js')}}></script>` line for all the scripts I have downloaded.

Comment: Check if your layout contains this script, In case you use one `layout`

Comment: Hi! These are in the app.layout underneath the @content. I checked all the separate pages, and no where HighCharts is called again.

Comment: In the page which contains `<script type="text/javascript" src={{asset('/js/highcharts.js')}}></script>` do you have loaded and `highstock.js` ?

Comment: Thank you @Alexandru-lonut Mihai.. After searching and trial and error I found that to be the problem. Didn't know that highcharts and highstock could conflict! could you post this as an answer?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, Please see now.